# Helly-Bray Theorem for continuous functions with compact support

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, weak-convergence

Helly-Bray Theorem states:

> Given distribution function $F_n$ and $F$, then $F_n$ weakly converges to $F$ if and only if $\int fd F_n \to \int fdF$ for every **bounded continuous function** $f$.

**Question**: Is the above theorem still true if '**bounded continuous function**' is replaced by '**continuous function with compact support**'?

I'm interested in this question because Riesz Representation Theorem on LCH spaces is stated for continuous functions with compact support. I'm also told that there are connections between weak convergence of distribution functions and weak star convergence in $C_b(\mathbb R)$, the space of bounded continuous functions. I wonder whether $C_b(\mathbb R)$ can be replaced by $C_c(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: This seems to be Exercise 25.13(b) in Billingsley's Probability and Measure. This would suggest it's true, but I have yet to work out the details.